# Expo-av Sound Interruption when app is in background

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I have built and a sample app which triggers small sound "turn left" &"turn right" when you pass (by running for example) in the certain location. The app works when it stays in foreground but it can not interrupt any other sound resources ( apple music, spotify etc.) when it stays to background (user changes the other app).

Do you have any solutions or suggestions?

Thank you

My Code for Expo AudioPlayer

```
const AudioPlayer = (props: Props) => {
const [sound, setSound] = useState(null);
const [isPlaying, setPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if(props.audio){
        (async () =>{
            const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
                {uri: props.audio}
            );
            await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
                allowsRecordingIOS: false,
                staysActiveInBackground: true,
                interruptionModeIOS: InterruptionModeIOS.DoNotMix,
                playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
                shouldDuckAndroid: true,
                interruptionModeAndroid: InterruptionModeAndroid.DoNotMix,
                playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false
            });
            setSound(sound as any);
            if(props.autoPlay){
                await sound.playAsync();
                setPlaying(true);
                await sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
            }
        })();
    }
}, []);
// other settings
}
```